# How to refresh a GridView in Extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs3

I am using a gridview which is binding data from datastore dynamically.
I have two textbox to enter data into grid.
On submit button click the textbox data I am adding to my datastore (no need to store in backend).
Now I want to refresh my gridview with datastore.

My Code:

```
_createEmptyRecord: function () {

var emptyrecord = Ext.data.Record.create(["id", "name", "type"]);

        return new emptyrecord({
            formula_id: 1,
            name: Amit,
            type: anything
        });
    },


    _addValuetogrid: function () {
        var record = this._createEmptyRecord();
        this._store.insert(0, record);
    },
_refreshgrid: function()
{

this._grid._addValuetogrid();

},
```

Now how to refresh my Gridview ?

Please help me...

Comment: Capslock broken?

Comment: PLEASE DON'T SHOUT *(I've fixed it for you on this occasion)*

Answer (score 13):

Ext.grid.GridView has refresh() method.

```
this._grid.getView().refresh();
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe a refresh function similar to this (untested) will work for Extjs 4;

```
_refreshgrid: function()
    {
        this._grid.getActiveView().refresh(true);
    }
```